# check if timestamp is old than 24 hours - Javascript

Tags: javascript, timestamp, nedb

I'm using the `Date.now()` function to get the timestamp when an api call is made. I'm storing it in the database powered by `nedb-promises`. How I can use it later in the code to check if a new api call is necessary to update the stored data? I want to check at least once a day.

```
db.definitions.find({}).then( (results) => {
  if( results.length > 0 ){
    console.log(results);
    if( Math.round(new Date().getTime() / 1000) - results.lastUpdate >= 86400 ){
      updateDefinitions().then( (filters) => {
        db.definitions.update({}, { $set: {filters} }, { returnUpdatedDocs: true }).then( (result) => {
          console.log(result);
          advServers.push(results.filters.easylist);
          trackingServers.push(results.filters.easyprivacy);
        });
      });
    }else{
      console.log("definitions already up to date");
      advServers.push(results.easylist);
      trackingServers.push(results.easyprivacy);
    }
  }else{
    updateDefinitions().then( (filters) => {
      console.log(filters);
      db.definitions.insert({ filters }).then( (result) => {
        console.log(result);
        advServers.push(results.filters.easylist);
        trackingServers.push(results.filters.easyprivacy);
      });
    });
  }
});
```

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: @evolutionxbox see the code

Comment: I am not really sure what you need, but setTimout() and/or setInterval() may help, both of them calls up a function with a timer, but they work different in their specific intrinsic way. 
You may check the documentations: 
[setInterval()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setInterval) 
[setTimeout()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-AUS/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setTimeout) 
[Timeouts and Intervals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Asynchronous/Timeouts_and_intervals)

Comment: @ErniSouza I need to check if the timestamp is elasped and is older than 24 hours. I know about the functions you've suggested but this isn't the use case for them, I need to do a check, not set a timeout or an interval.